How to reconnect to server via OpenVPN on server restart?
A Server that I connect to can be down for several hours due connection problems. So every morning I have to check the OpenVPN connection and reconnect to the server if needed. I'm tired of this routine.
Is there any way to try to connect to the server every hour or so?
Problem that I've never really worked with OpenVPN and its config option looks all the same to me.
Is it true that these settings allow the client to try to connect to the server every hour an unlimited number of times?
connect-retry 3600
connect-retry-max unlimited

Client - Windows.  
Server - idk, don't have an access to server

Current client config:
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote <server> <port>
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert cert.crt
key key.key
remote-cert-tls server
tls-auth ta.key 1
cipher AES-256-GCM
keepalive 10 20
connect-retry 15
connect-retry-max 25
verb 3
auth-user-pass pass.txt
auth-retry nointeract
auth-nocache


This already will reconnect, due to connect-retry. See man openvpn for details about this and other options in the config.

To reconnect to a server via OpenVPN after a server restart, I make sure the OpenVPN client is set to auto-start and use options like persist-tun and persist-key to maintain the connection state. I also set up a retry mechanism with options like reconnect or keepalive to automatically attempt reconnections. Additionally, I might use a script to monitor server availability and trigger reconnection attempts when needed. It's important to check that the server configuration allows for client reconnections too.
